# How can I export users, forums and comments to another site?

Tags: importing-exporting

I need to move forums containers, topics, their associated comments, and user accounts to another existing Drupal site.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to export into a live site where there already exists forums, topics, nodes, comment users that you not want to overwrite, I suggest you check out the 
[Drupal-to-Drupal data migration](http://drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d) module.  It will let you move the data and refactor it in the process.